# <S-Arrows> weird behavior (<S-UP>,<S-DOWN>,<S-LEFT>,<S-RIGHT>)

Tags: key-bindings

```
<S-DOWN>
```

Moves the cursor back a few characters. But not always by the same amount.

```
<S-UP>
```

Moves the cursor to the end of the line.

```
<S-LEFT>
```

Deletes the next two lines.

```
<S-RIGHT>
```

Deletes the next two lines, adds empty line, enters insert mode at said empty line.

This happens in any mode, visual, insert and normal mode.

Looking at h:index, it says noting about this behavior. If I enter

```
unmap <S-LEFT>
```

or any other mentioned command, I am prompted with the "no mapping" message.

Any idea what is happening, and how to prevent it?

#### EDIT

I also tried adding

```
map ^[[1;2B <Nop>
```

where ^[[1;2B is the result of pressing Ctrl+v . But than, upon pressing  I am prompted with

> E486: Pattern not found:

Also note that after adding such mapping for all the combinations, the

```
<S-UP>
<S-LEFT>
```

work, meaning, they do nothing. But for

```
<S-DOWN>
<S-LEFT>
```

I am prompted with the message

> E486: Pattern not found:

Answer (score 1):

As I have found the solution in the mean time, I will post it here.

One should set for vim what the correct escape keys are. In my sitution, this means that I had to add

```
set <S-UP>=[1;2A
set <S-DOWN>=[1;2B
set <S-LEFT>=[1;2D
set <S-RIGHT>=[1;2C
```

into the .vimrc. The rhs is generated by pressing Ctrl+v+. Now the sequences behave as specified in the h:index.